# Convert N and E values to RSA public key for OpenSSL?

Tags: json, openssl, ip-camera

I'm working on automating activation for an IP camera, and I've got an annoyance: The camera spits out JSON for encryption - something like:

```
{ {"params":{"asymmetric":"RSA","cipher":["AES","RPAC"],"pub":"N:CD1C1ECB40E9BD8E04FDB6515A892E03DF007ABF107A829C10B08D267EBA1A11811356C20F28D204B5412B0F6E1C254F85D9A59322CFE57A12A9E12B2944752C20F54A6D7D59853E745F7C30C3D7D806B87747F7F559A99B7C69A7E41A538B62A1DB1723631974F766C061982852FF7FB3A15E824E28BEC63DF9B0F7354F5DC29986D736DDD16AC2D82661D203BA637E544E9F0EDC7B271C6D9BE87BDA8D43416B36D66E00BBD4EB34E3306090E1BD3493990919CEBA937B456C468393A207C73562E584E50C16CB06C394351D34C0EBA51D4135C8FD993948CADF6C6810B91BC8F8FE713CDA917CD7EA49E1A927CA130F258F05B056EB5C009E21446A9D4D07,E:010001"},"result":true}
```

... and I need to go from those N and E values to a public cert that openssl can use, so that I can encode new admin credentials to send back to the camera.  Thoughts?

Comment: Does this help: [From ExpKey + Modkey to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453569/1380680)?

Comment: It's essentially the same problem... in my specific case, though, "pip install cryptography" spits out command not found, "yum list pip" spits out no matching packages, and "yum provides *bin/pip" spits out no matches found. So the solution isn't usable as-is.

Comment: What version of `python` are you using? What Linux distro exactly? How about this one: [Cannot install python-pip with yum](https://superuser.com/questions/1137207/cannot-install-python-pip-with-yum)

Comment: @reinierTorenbeek Python 2.6.6, CentOS 6.10 (LTS, yes, I'm aware I need to replace it by Nov. 2020). Checking repos... and that went boom quick. Turned on epel-release, installed python-pip.  pip install crytography said I needed pip 18, and I should update. Updating pip worked. When I went to pip install cryptography again, it spat out a syntax error.

Comment: Ah -- that answer was written for Python 3. I will see if I can update it to work with Python 2 as well. Feel free to add your remarks to that particular question.

Comment: I have updated that answer and tested with `python2`. Basically, the old `print` was the problem. Let me know if that works, or add a comment to that question itself.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek ... I should have been clearer. 
pip install cryptography -> Command not found.
yum install python-pip -> OK.
pip install cryptography -> Said I needed pip 18, and suggested I update.
pip install --upgrade pip -> Said it worked.
pip install cryptography -> Spat out a syntax error.
**pip** spat out the error - not your script - when attempting to meet the dependencies of the very helpful script.

Comment: Ah, OK. Do you want to discuss in [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181293/install-pip) to try and resolve it?

Comment: No... security reasons. I could just go through pip (it's a python script itself) and correct the listed problems as I encounter them.  However, this is ultimately for a production machine for mass distribution, and that would cause some nasty maintenance issues (break on update, specifically).  If it was a one-off, that wouldn't be a problem, but it isn't, so it is. Right now I'm digging through base definitions of things to see if I can make it work OK with echo, cat, and xxd.  Thank you, though.

Comment: OK, that is a difficult task though. The example structure on [this page about ASN.1 sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCertEnroll/about-sequence) happens to be a public key in ASN.1 format. That is what you will ultimately need to create. The page says "2 minutes to read" :-) . Hope this helps...

Comment: How far have you come with your research? Do you have a github or somewhere I can contact you?